# WSO2 ESB unable to remove ws-security header in the response before DSS call

Tags: ws-security, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service which needs to call a exernal service with ws security. I have to
call the service, and based on the response, I need to extract some information
and then call a data service to update the database. As I get the response and create the
payload to call the data service it is also having the ws security header which ends up in an exception.

I have used

`<header action="remove" name="wsse:Security" scope="default"
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" />`

while creating and calling the data service but end up with no luck.

Below is my proxy service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="EDI_Test_Proxy_2" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
    transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value="get_mcash_data" />
            <property name="Content-Type" scope="transport" type="STRING"
                value="application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action=get_mcash_data" />
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <address trace="disable"
                        uri="http://localhost:9770/services/my_fetch_data_service" />
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property expression="//mc:mcash/mc:tran_id/text()" name="tran_id"
                scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:mc="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
                xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" />
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$ctx:tran_id" name="tran_id" />
            </log>
            <filter xmlns:mc="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                xpath="boolean(//mc:mcash/mc:mobile_no)">
                <then>
                    <property expression="//mc:mcash/mc:tran_id/text()" name="tran_id"
                        scope="default" type="STRING" />
                    <property expression="//mc:mcash/mc:mobile_no/text()"
                        name="mobile_no" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                    <property expression="//mc:mcash/mc:tran_amt/text()" name="tran_amt"
                        scope="default" type="STRING" />
                    <property expression="//mc:mcash/mc:tran_date/text()"
                        name="tran_date" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                    <property expression="//mc:mcash/mc:tran_time/text()"
                        name="tran_time" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                    <property expression="//mc:mcash/mc:part_tran_srl_num/text()"
                        name="part_tran_srl_num" scope="default" type="STRING" />
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:tran_id" name="tran_id" />
                        <property expression="$ctx:mobile_no" name="mobile_no" />
                        <property expression="$ctx:tran_amt" name="tran_amt" />
                        <property expression="$ctx:tran_date" name="tran_date" />
                        <property expression="$ctx:tran_time" name="tran_time" />
                        <property expression="$ctx:part_tran_srl_num" name="tran_time" />
                    </log>
                    <payloadFactory description="pf_mcash" media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <flw:purchaceFromMMR xmlns:flw="http://flw.mwt.mobitel.com/">
                                <!--Optional: -->
                                <bankPurchaseRequest xmlns="">
                                    <amount>$1</amount>
                                    <!--Optional: -->
                                    <bankCode>XXX</bankCode>
                                    <!--Optional: -->
                                    <date>$2</date>
                                    <!--Optional: -->
                                    <mobile>$3</mobile>
                                    <!--Optional: -->
                                    <time>$4</time>
                                    <!--Optional: -->
                                    <transactionId>$5</transactionId>
                                </bankPurchaseRequest>
                            </flw:purchaceFromMMR>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:tran_amt" />
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:tran_date" />
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:mobile_no" />
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:tran_time" />
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:tran_id" />
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <call>
                        <endpoint>
                            <address trace="disable"
                                uri="https://my_external_web_service/to_be/called?wsdl">
                                <enableSec policy="gov:ws-policy/sample_policy.xml" />
                            </address>
                        </endpoint>
                    </call>
                    <loopback />
                </then>
                <else>
                    <log>
                        <property name="STATUS" value="*****No data available*****" />
                    </log>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <header action="remove" name="wsse:Security" scope="default"
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" />
            <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default" />
            <property expression="//return/mobile/text()" name="mobile"
                scope="default" type="STRING" />
            <property expression="//return/date/text()" name="date"
                scope="default" type="STRING" />
            <property expression="//return/recipetNo/text()" name="recipetNo"
                scope="default" type="STRING" />
            <property expression="//return/resultCode/text()" name="resultCode"
                scope="default" type="STRING" />
            <property expression="//return/resultDesc/text()" name="resultDesc"
                scope="default" type="STRING" />
            <payloadFactory description="pf_mcash_update"
                media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <p:TestUpdate xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence -->
                        <p:trf_status>$1</p:trf_status>
                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence -->
                        <p:resp_code>$2</p:resp_code>
                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence -->
                        <p:receipt>$3</p:receipt>
                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence -->
                        <p:rsp_message>$4</p:rsp_message>
                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence -->
                        <p:tran_id>$5</p:tran_id>
                        <!--Exactly 1 occurrence -->
                        <p:part_tran_srl_num>$6</p:part_tran_srl_num>
                    </p:TestUpdate>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg value="10" />
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:resultCode" />
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:recipetNo" />
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:resultDesc" />
                    <arg value="SDC311521" />
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:part_tran_srl_num" />
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value="TestUpdate" />
            <property name="Content-Type" scope="transport" type="STRING"
                value="application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action=TestUpdate" />
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <address trace="disable"
                        uri="http://my_internal_data_service/which_ends_up_with/ws_sec_header" />
                </endpoint>
            </call>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence />
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the following log mediator before the call mediator in the outsequence and update this with the output logs.
it will help us to identify the issue.

```
<log level="full">
            <property name="OutSequence" value="==== OUTSEQ ===="/>
   </log>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I'm in will update with requests ASAP,  In the mean time just for clarification I have engaged rampart in the `<ESB_HOME>repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml`  like following `<!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--             Global Engaged Modules                -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->

    <!-- Comment this out to disable Addressing -->
    <module ref="addressing"/>
    <module ref="rampart" /> `   is this correct? Is it like global engagement where all services engage rampart?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I have engaged rampart module `<module ref="rampart" />` in the axis2.xml found in `<ESB_HOME>repository/conf/axis2/` . After commenting out this line the exception was gone and the dss call worked. The reason I believe, if this line of code is enabled, ws-securiy is engaged globally and all the service calls will look for ws-security header. Please correct me if I'm wrong in anyway.