# How to remove ws-security header on WSO2 ESB?

Tags: proxy, header, wso2, esb, ws-security

I have a proxy with ws-security on WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus 4.9.0.

When I try a call to WSO2 DSS, it responds with an error, because there is ws-security header inside my request payload, and DSS can't accept this.

I tried to remove header with Header Meadiator, but it doesn't works.

I saw another post here on Stack Overflow, but it didn't help me because the tag to remove to solve the problem doesn't exists on my axis.xml file ([WSO2 ESB unable to remove ws-security header in the response before DSS call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908148/wso2-esb-unable-to-remove-ws-security-header-in-the-response-before-dss-call))

**How can I remove ws-security header? There is any way to stop propagating ws-security header over my proxy?**

Comment: Can you post the way (configuration) you tried to remove header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your configuration, which is used for removing the header. It should be similar to following configuration:

```
<syn:header name="wsse:Security" action="remove" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
```

You can refer WSO2 Documentation for more references [1][2]

And for the stack overflow issue ([WSO2 ESB unable to remove ws-security header in the response before DSS call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908148/wso2-esb-unable-to-remove-ws-security-header-in-the-response-before-dss-call)) you mentioned in your question is about adding wrong module in to axis2.xml. It was done by the user and became the reason for that issue. That is why you can't find that module in axis2.xml.

Please refer documentation and change your configurations accordingly.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+100%3A+Using+WS-Security+for+Outgoing+Messages

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+200%3A+Using+WS-Security+with+policy+attachments+for+proxy+services